# How can I find an old copy of my .bash_profile file?

Tags: macos, terminal, bash

I accidentally ran a script that changed how my terminal (macOS Sierra) looked by completely changing all the code in .bash_profile getting rid of the Python paths as well. I would like to know if it is possible to find the previously saved version of .bash_profile so that I can revert to it.

EDIT: I had been looking at the hidden files in my home directory when I noticed that Anaconda had made a backup file: .bash_profile-anaconda.bak that had most of all of my code at the time I installed Anaconda. It may not solve all the problems but it partly works. Thanks Gordon Davisson for mentioning Time Machine as I didn't consider that even though I backed up my computer the day before.

Comment: Do you have a backup (e.g. with Time Machine)?

Comment: I didn't think of that. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

No copy of .bash_profile is made. You need to find in backups if you have any.